# Matching array elements to get an array element at another index

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a PHP array that I'm using to generate an HTML form. The PHP array is this:

```
<?php
$vdb = array (
        array(  "Alabama",              275),
        array(  "Alaska",               197),
        array(  "Arizona",              3322));
?>
```

The PHP to generate the HTML form is below. I need to have the value be the name of the state, because there is some AJAX I'm using to display which states a user has chosen.

```
<?php
    echo "<table border='1'><thead><tr><th></th><th>State</th><th>Contacts</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>";
    for ($row = 0; $row < 42; $row++) {
        echo "<tr><td class='input_button'><input type='checkbox' name='vdb[]' value='".$vdb[$row][0]."' title='".$vdb[$row][1]."' /></td>";
        echo "<td>".$vdb[$row][0]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$vdb[$row][1]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is, on submission of the form, with the states the user selected, loop through the PHP array and total the numbers from the selected states. So if I checked Alabama and Alaska, I'd want to add 275 + 197.

This is what I thought would have worked, but it's not:

```
<?php
    $vendors = array();
    if (isset($_POST["vdb"])) {
        $vendors = $_POST["vdb"];
    }

    $ven_i = 0;
    $ven_j = 0;
    $ven_total = 0;
    foreach ($vendors as $value) {
        foreach ($vdb as $vdb_value) {
            if ($vendors[$ven_i] == $vdb[$ven_j][0]) {
                $ven_total += $vdb[$ven_j][1];                                   
            }
            $ven_j++;
        }
        $ven_i++;
    }
?>
```

and then $ven_total should be the total I'm looking for. However, $ven_total just ends up being the first checkbox selected, and it ignores the rest. I am doing this correctly with the AJAX, displaying the total on the front end, but I don't know how to pass that on to the form submission. I'd rather not using GET and URL variables, because a user could type something into the URL and modify the count. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or a better way to approach this that I would be able to understand? (Very much a novice programmer.)

Comment: How is the `$vdb` array being built? Is that coming from a `mysql_query` or something? Is it statically coded?

Comment: If you are never using $value or $vdb_value AND are doing index++ calls, why are you using foreach instead of a normal for?

Comment: @smotchkkiss $vdb is a static array, numbers are updated manually every couple of weeks/months.

@unholysampler I guess I could use for, I was using foreach because it automatically stops at the end of the array, right? I wouldn't have to worry about iterating one too many or one too few times. And actually, I guess I could use $value instead of $vendors[$ven_i]

Comment: why aren't you using keyed arrays instead of two-element arrays for each item? E.g., `array('Alabama' => 275)` instead of `array('Alabama', 275)`?

Comment: I actually also have one additional integer associated with the array, just wanted to simplify it for the post here. So Alabama actually has 275 Contacts and 210 Emails. Is there a way to key two items? (Like I said, pretty new to this. Exciting to get where I've gotten, but I run into a lot of brick walls. :P) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is going to end up having a couple different suggestions, but bear with me.
First off, using a list as a data structure gets messy because you end up forgetting what index 1 actually means. So, since you have more than just a pairing of name to value, you can try making it a basic class and make your code more readable.

```
<?php
class State {
    public $name;
    public $contact_count;
    public $email_count;

    function __construct($name, $contact_count, $email_count) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->contact_count = $contact_count;
        $this->email_count = $email_count;
    }
}

$states = array (
    new State("Alabama", 275, 210),
    new State("Alaska", 197, 149),
    new State("Arizona", 3322, 2145));

$selected_vendors = array("Alabama", "Arizona");

$ven_total = 0;
foreach ($selected_vendors as $selected) {
    foreach ($states as $state) {
        if ($selected == $state->name) {
            $ven_total += $state->contact_count;                                   
        }
    }
}
echo $ven_total
?>
```

This is still your code just cleaned up some. The looping and adding seems to be working fine. Have you done `print_r($_POST)` to make sure you are getting the values the way you expect? You mentioned not wanting to use GET, but POST can be spoofed just like GET, always validate input from the user.

Comment: Thanks unholysampler. I know it's been a few days but I'm just getting back to this project and this solution looks a LOT cleaner than what I currently have. I'll give it a shot.

Yeah, I need to validate this form, but was having trouble getting jQuery validate to work with the FormToWizard jQuery plugin I'm using to turn this thing into a wizard. Thanks for the help though, I will test it out!

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to understand what I wrote. Remember to accept if it ends up being the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the number as a key to the $vdb array ?

```
    $vdb = array (
            array( 275=>"Alabama" ),
            array( 197=>"Alaska" ),
            array( 3322=>"Arizona" )
    );
```

and then

```
$sum = array_intersect($vdb, $vendors);
$total = 0;
foreach ($sum as $key=>$value) {
   $total = $total+$key;
}
unset($key, $value, $sum);
```

The array_intersect() function compares two or more arrays, and returns an array with the keys and values from the first array, only if the value is present in all of the other arrays.

Comment: Maybe I should have included this in the original post, but the array actually looks like this:
$vdb = array (
  //  State     #  Email
  array( "Alabama",     275,  210),
  array( "Alaska",     197,  149),
  array( "Arizona",     3322, 2145));